# Can't get data from simple json file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I have local json file from which I have to retrieve data.

That's my code:

```
 const myReq = new Request('./data.json')
        fetch(myReq)
            .then(rawD=> rawD.json())
            .then(info =>  console.log(info))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Like that I get an error  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` - on the fetch(myReq) line. And if I remove the `rawD.json()` row , I have a Response

```
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
```

etc.

But I can't access the actual data in the json file

Comment: can you show us what the json file looks like?

Comment: The error is indicating that there is a syntax error in the json file. You can check for such things here: https://jsonchecker.com/

Comment: @Neeko here is it
```{
    "success":true,
    "timestamp":1596461944,
    "base":"EUR",
    "date":"2020-08-03",
    "rates":
        {
            "USD":1.17055,
            "AUD":1.652887,
            "CAD":1.573722,
            "BGN":1.952208
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `data.json` is a local file, meaning you can access it in your file manager where your app is being developed, I would recommend doing something as simple as this:

`import data from './data.json'` or `const data = require('./data.json')`

and then use it as usually:

```
import data from './data.json'

data.map((item) => console.log(item))
```

If this is going to be an external data.json, you might want to resort to modules such as `fetch` or `axios`

Comment: Actually it needs to be fetch and

Comment: Hi @Irenkaaa In order for me to help you, I would need some explanation as to why it needs to be fetch? Will it be something like `https://www.something.com/data.json` ?

Comment: It is a task, it says that I need to load the info from the json file using http request. And needs to be in the ComponentDidMount ... I am kind of newbie and I don't know other way that fetch :)